# Prove that I -xx* is singular if and only x*x = 1

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

(=>) Suppose  I - xx* is singular if and only there is a y such that (I−xx*)y=0, i.e. xx* y=y. Now set λ=x* y. Then y=λx, i.e. xx* λx=λx
Thus λx(x* x) = λx => x* x = 1

(<=) Suppose x*x = 1

Please help

Comment: 'Singular' means that $U$ does not have an inverse.  Your equation $U^2=I$ means that $U$ has an inverse, which is itself.

Comment: oops my bad. I was looking at the wrong problem and used that for singular. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just start from the basics. $I-xx^*$ is singular if and only there is a $y$ such that $(I-xx^*)y=0$, i.e. such that $xx^*y=y$. Now set $\lambda=x^*y$. Then $y=\lambda x$, i.e. $xx^*\lambda x=\lambda x$, and you have almost proved one direction.

Make sure that you are aware at each step which expressions are scalars.

Comment: Thanks I will be aware of that

Answer (score 1):

On top of the fact that your standing fragment of a proof is mostly incomprehensible, note that for matrices: $AB = 0$ does **not** imply $A = 0$ or $B = 0$.

**Hint:** Note that $xx^*$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $\|x\|^2 = x^*x$. A matrix is singular if and only if $0$ is one of its eigenvalues.

**Alternative approach:** assuming $x \neq 0$, extend $\frac{x}{\|x\|}$ into an orthonormal basis.  Find the matrix of $I - xx^*$ relative to this basis.

Comment: I get that xx* has eval 0 but I want to use the fact given that xx*=1, and I don't know how to connect both of them together :(

Comment: If you know the eigenvalues of $xx^*$, you can immediately deduce the eigenvalues of $I - xx^*$.  The fact that $x^*x$ is an eigenvalue of $xx^*$ is one way of "connecting both of them together".

Comment: alrite. Thanks for the hint ;)